# Type of date fields in MongoDB (and sorting them)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql

What should be the type of a date field in MongoDB?

a) a `String` like `"2013-10-03T08:30:23.094Z"`

or

b) a `ISODate` object like `ISODate("2013-10-15T14:49:46.847Z")`

Which one of those will let me sort by date/time?

Comment: The problem with string is lexicographic sorting, i.e. 10 comes before 9 in normal sort, alsl it is larger and incompatible with some parts of MongoDB as a date

Comment: @Sammaye so I should use a proper ISODate object for storing date/time?

Comment: I would say so, it is a lot better and more designed for dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely use the `ISODate`:

- It can be used with the [aggregation framework date operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/operator-date/) such as `$day`, `$hour`, `$dayOfWeek`, etc.
- It consumes a lot [less memory](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification), the string needs 28 bytes (20 chars + null terminator + prepended int32 string length + 3 bytes padding), the `ISODate` needs a mere 8 bytes (an int64)

In ISO 8601 format, lexicographic and chronological sorting are equivalent, except for negative dates, so `$gt` and `$lt` also work on strings.